# creating a download limited link

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to charge people to watch my video. They buy and get a link. How can i make that link destroy after usage? any ideas? third party?

Comment: I disagree -- we won't necessarily give him teh codez, but we can tell him some strategies for implementing this.

Comment: I know others don't mind spending time helping people who can't be bothered to click a `Vote` or `Accept` link every now and again as thanks, but I'm not among those folks. Hence why I said **"I"** in my comment. :p

Answer (score 1):

Embed a single-use code in the URL; invalidate it after a single use.

Comment: And please please make sure you don't sequentially assign them... go in a semi-random order.